# Angular ng-Repeat with checkboxes storing choices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Angular 1.4

I have a simple `ng-repeat` with a check box. The goal is to have the `customer.Id` added into the `$scope.holdsChosenCustomerIds`. I need `$scope.holdsChosenCustomerIds`  to be dumb array like [3,78,445,789], basically whatever the user selects.

```
$scope.holdsChosenCustomerIds= [];
```

---

```
 <div ng-repeat="customer in customers">   
     <input type='checkbox' ng-model="holdsChosenCustomerIds[$index]==???" ????????? /> 
 </div>
```

stuck at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use instance of ng-repeat as model

Like this

```
 <div ng-repeat="customer in customers">   
     <input type='checkbox' ng-model="customer.isChecked" /> 
 </div>
```

You can get info of checked item from `$scope.customers`

If you need checked true item

you can try like this

```
$scope.holdsChosenCustomerIds= $scope.customers.filter(function(x){ return x.isChecked; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this in your HTML using `ng-change`:

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in customers">   
    <input type='checkbox' ng-model="customer.selected" ng-change="selectUnselect()" /> 
</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.selectUnselect = function() {
    var customer = this.customer;
    if (customer.selected) {
         $scope.holdsChosenCustomerIds.push(customer.id);
    } else {
         var idIndex = $scope.holdsChosenCustomerIds.indexOf(customer.id);
         if (idIndex > -1) {
             $scope.holdsChosenCustomerIds.splice(idIndex, 1);
         }
    }
};
```